# Wald Statistic Simplification - 2 Restrictions?

Tags: multiple-regression, covariance-matrix, misspecification, wald-test

(Specify the wald statistic as: W=$(R\hat{\theta}-r)'[R\hat{V}(\hat{\theta})R']^{-1}(R\hat{\theta}-r)$

Where r is a vector of restrictions, R imposes the restrictions on $\hat{\beta}$, $\hat{\theta}$ is an estimate of our unknown parameters, $\theta = (\beta',\sigma^2)'$ and $\hat{V}$ is a consistent covariance matrix estimator.

The wald statistic simplifies to W=$\frac{\hat{\gamma}^2}{\hat{V}_{k+2,k+2}}$ under a single restriction. Where $\gamma$ is the restriction coefficient, i.e. what is being specified under the null hypothesis. Would anyone be kind enough to tell me how this simplifies down and what the simplification would be for 2 restrictions?

Thank you

EDIT: Suggestion by Dimitriy

```
residuals2_r<-t(residuals(fit.lpm))%*%residuals(fit.lpm)
residuals2_u<-t(residuals(fit.lpm_u))%*%residuals(fit.lpm_u)
num=residuals2_r-residuals2_u/2
den=residuals2_u/(12000-16)
num/den
```

Comment: I think your code is still wrong: $(A-B)/2 \ne A - B/2$. You want the former, but have the latter above.

Comment: Okay thanks Dimitriy, a stupid mistake I made, I got a value of 20.08, which is relatively close to what I get when I use waldtest(), 15.485. It's possible that waldtest() puts a weight on the result?

Comment: I don't think so. They should be the same. I would create a reproducible example on a public dataset that illustrates the problem you are having and start another question. This is verging on off-topic for this forum, so Stackoverflow may be a better place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a linear equality constraint of the form $R\beta=r$, where $R$ is a $q \times k$ matrix of known constants, with $q<k$; r is a $q-$vector of known constants; $k$ is the number of variables in the model (including intercept) and $q$ is the number of restrictions.

The test statistic with $q$ restrictions would be

$$F=\cfrac{\cfrac{e_{*}'e_{*} -e'e }{q}}{\cfrac{e'e}{n-k}} \sim F(q,n-k), $$

where $e_{*}'e_{*}$ is the RSS from the restricted model and $e'e$ is the unrestricted RSS.

Here is an example showing the equivalence in Stata on the cars dataset with $k=4,q=4, \textrm{ and}\: n=74$,:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. /* Unconstrained Model */
. reg price mpg weight foreign

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 70)        =     23.29
       Model |   317252881         3   105750960   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   317812515        70  4540178.78   R-squared       =    0.4996
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.4781
       Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =    2130.8

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |    21.8536   74.22114     0.29   0.769    -126.1758     169.883
      weight |   3.464706    .630749     5.49   0.000     2.206717    4.722695
     foreign |    3673.06   683.9783     5.37   0.000     2308.909    5037.212
       _cons |  -5853.696   3376.987    -1.73   0.087    -12588.88    881.4934
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. scalar URSS = e(rss)

. test weight == mpg ==3

 ( 1)  - mpg + weight = 0
 ( 2)  weight = 3

       F(  2,    70) =    0.40
            Prob > F =    0.6736

. display "Wald F-stat = " r(F) 
Wald F-stat = .39740249

. /* Constrained Model */
. gen p2 = price - 3*(mpg + weight)

. regress p2 foreign

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 72)        =     37.74
       Model |   168459665         1   168459665   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   321421072        72  4464181.55   R-squared       =    0.3439
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3348
       Total |   489880737        73  6710695.03   Root MSE        =    2112.9

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          p2 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |    3301.04   537.3704     6.14   0.000     2229.812    4372.269
       _cons |  -3938.404   293.0011   -13.44   0.000    -4522.491   -3354.317
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. scalar RRSS = e(rss)

. display "My Wald F-stat= " ((scalar(RRSS) - scalar(URSS))/2)/(scalar(URSS)/(70))
My Wald F-stat= .39740249
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, however I specifically need the wald statistic and this is the F statistic.

Comment: Why would they be different in this case?

Comment: I have been given a specific task for which I need the wald statistic, an F test would be good if I was just interested in finding the effect of omitted variables.

Comment: I believe when the covariance matrix is estimated, this Wald statistic converges in distribution to an F, so they are equivalent. It’s similar to how with the single restriction case you use the t-distribution. The variables are also not omitted, they have restrictions placed on the coefficients.

Comment: These are all Wald statistics even if the distributions vary.

Comment: I tried estimating this in R and unfortunately, I got the wrong answer:                                               
residuals2_r<-t(residuals(fit.lpm))%*%residuals(fit.lpm)
      residuals2_u<-t(residuals(fit.lpm_u))%*%residuals(fit.lpm_u)
     num=(residuals2_r-residuals2_u/15)
     den=residuals2_u/(12000-15)
     num/den

Comment: Hard to tell from incomplete code pasted into the comments, but I think your formula is not quite correct. You need `num=(residuals2_r-residuals2_u)/q`, where q is be the number of restrictions, and should be less than 15 since you need an intercept in the restricted model. Your original questions would have $q=2$. So fix the right parentheses and $q$, and you should get Wald F stat that is correct.